# При замене фрагмента новый фрагмент не перекрывает старый

Tags: android, android-fragment

Всем привет. Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой при замене фрагмента,старый фрагмент остается виден под новым фрагментом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально при запуске приложения появляется фрагмент  приветствия с картинкой, затем фрагменты меняются но экран приветствия остается.
Вот мой код

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            R.anim.enter_from_right,
            R.anim.exit_to_right
        )
        .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, FoodAnalysisFragment())
        .commit()

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:navGraph = "@navigation/mobile_navigation"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    />
```

Так же есть еще вторая проблема. Я скрыл toolbar в стартовом фрагменте с приветствием и при вызове следующего фрагмента я обратно показываю toolbar, но toolbar отображается с предыдущего фрагмента

так я прячу toolbar в стартовом фрагменте

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
```

и аналогичным способом отображаю toolbar  в новом фрагменте но в место hide() вызываю show().
Как сделать так чтоб после показа экрана с приветствием я больше не мог обращаться к нему?
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: нужен код полностью, как вы вставляете стартовый фрагмент

Comment: @Style-7 стартовый фрагмент я вставляю с помощью навигации. Вот ссылки на скриншоты - http://prntscr.com/tc930h , это код м MainActivity - http://prntscr.com/tc93jc

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете второму фрагменту сделать непрозрачный фон (т.е. явно указать белый цвет фона к примеру), и тогда вы не будете видеть нижний фрагмент.

Comment: я изменил фон второго фрагмента таким способом ` android:background="?android:windowBackground"` , это помогло, первого фрагмента больше не видно. Но получается первый фрагмент все равно остается под низом  и я всегда могу к нему вернуться с помощью стрелки назад на устройстве. То есть теперь возникла проблема как удалить первый фрагмент чтоб к нему нельзя уже было вернуться

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в разметке поместит контейнер

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"/>
```

а уже в нем делать replace, иначе у вас как я понял fragment сам становится контейнером, что приводит к этому эффекту.
Первый фрагмент также должен быть помещен в этот контейнер.

Comment: Пробовал, то же самое получается. Я использую навигацию в приложении, по этому у меня fragment  а не FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы Вам сначала не удалить первый фрагмент, а потом просто добавить второй?

Что-то типа:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .remove(первый фрагмент)
        .add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, FoodAnalysisFragment(), "food_analysis_tag");
        .commit();
```

Вы использовали статический вариант добавления фрагментов, где особо и не предполагается, что фрагменты будут удалять и добавлять.

Другое дело, использовать динамический вариант добавления фрагментов. В этом случае Вы просто создаете пустой контейнер, куда можете добавлять сколь угодно фрагментов [предварительно опустошая контейнер].